# Get the newest dictionary from a list in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a list of dictionaries and I want to get the latest one.

reviewing jinja2 docs it seems I should be able to do this:

```
    - set_fact:
    t:
      - a: 1
        b: 2
      - a: 3
        b: 1


- debug:
    msg: "{{ t | max(attribute='a') }}"
```

But that fails with

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
>      "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ t | max(attribute='a') }}): max() > got an unexpected keyword argument 'attribute'"
>   }

what is the best whay to do this? Of course my use case is harder than that small demo.
My think looks something like this:

```
 check_mode: no
  set_fact:
    tgs_info: "{{ tgs_info | default({}) | combine({ item: all_tg_info | to_json | from_json | json_query(query) | max(attribute='target_group_name') }) }}"
  vars:
    query: "target_groups[?contains(target_group_name, `{{ product }}`) == `true`] | [?ends_with(target_group_name, `{{ tg_suffix }}{{ item }}`) == `true`]"
  loop: "{{ projects | selectattr('protocol', 'match', '^HTTP$') | map(attribute='port') | list }}"
```

The idea is that `all_tg_info` contains all the autoscaling of my aws account. I filter them and I want to get the latest one based on the name or any other parameter.
I'm kind of stuk here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** As reported in @Hellseher comment below, from **ansible 2.11** release, `max|min(attribute='someattr')` will be available. The answer below will therefore become obsolete for this version and onward. See the [corresponding pull request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/50909#pullrequestreview-502124541).

---

> reviewing jinja2 docs it seems I should be able to do this...

Even though the [jinja2 builtin filters documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#max) mentions possible params for the `max` filter, there is an [open bug report](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50669) on ansible side to support those.

In this case you can easily acheive your requirement with the [`json_query` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter). Here is a demo playbook with your simplistic data (as I don't have your more elaborate one...). You can probably adapt this to your actual `json_query`.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    t:
      - a: 1
        b: 2
      - a: 3
        b: 1

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ t | json_query('max_by(@, &a)') }}"
```

Comment: Isn't the signature of jinja2 filter telling it receives parameters? `max(value, case_sensitive=False, attribute=None)` `attribute – Get the object with the max value of this attribute`

Comment: You are totally right !!!!! I've read the examples (without any params) so many times that I never actually looked further. It looks like ansible does not yet accept those params, as reported in the following bug  report: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50669

Comment: @nax I just updated my answer with our current discussion. Sorry for the doubt on you and thanks for your wise feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the issue, i didn't find it.. seems the PR is WIP for a year now so I'll try to use the json_query and see how it goes. Regarding signature.. yeah.. they don't reference to those params anywhere, making it hard to spot

Comment: `max(attribute)` will be available in Ansible 2.11+ https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/50909#pullrequestreview-502124541